# Office-js Open a New Window from the Ribbon/FunctionFile.js

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I am having trouble opening a window from the ribbon. I declared my button, which onclick triggers a function declared in the function-file.js. Works all fine. However, it won't exectute window.open. I can understand there might be some CORS-Problems. So I tested several things. First I declared the Websites URL in the

```
<AppDomains><AppDomain>Website-URL</AppDomain></AppDomains>
```

Didn't change anything. So I tried to debug localy. And it seems to work when I run the Add-in on localhost and call the Website that is hosted on the webserver (where CORS problems might occure, so this doesn't seem to be the problem). So I did the following:

```
var winHandle = window.open("https://website");
if (winHandle == null) {
    console.log('Window was blocked');
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://website/openWebsite.html');
}
```

The above code uses the displayDialog-api in case it can't open the window, which opens a site that then provides a button to trigger window.open. Because if I just set the new location it will give me a pop-up warning. And trying this with the VS-Debug functionality is working. It is not opening the window, but it opens the dialog and so I can finally open the window from the dialog. However, when the Manifest.xml is sideloaded it does not work.

Any suggestions to get window.open working from the function-file or at least the displayDialog?

---

**EDITED:**
As the second answer says: it is correct, the *first* page must indeed be in the same origin. However, what I encountered was a subdomain call, which the sideloaded Add-In could not perform. While in Visual Studios debug mode he only gave me a CORS warning and loaded it anyway.

**Original**
Oh and btw the dialog-api documentation says that displayDialog should not leave the domain in the first call. But it seems to be no problem when i directly call

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://someOtherDomain/website');
```

I guess you just need to specify the domain in the AppDomains.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you please add more details on what platform you are experiencing this? (win32, mac, ios or Online?) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are intended to operate without a UI. If you need to display information or interact with the user, you'll want to use a [ShowTaskpane action](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/action). You can point this action to any page in your app. Typically for this scenario we would create a page that executes the on load and then displays the results.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So will the dialogApi be not usable from the FunctionFile in the future as well? I wonder why the Ribbon functionality is so much reduced compared to the former Add-In types anyway?

Comment: @MAOg0espr0 It's definitely not reduced, just a year ago (may be a couple) we didn't have ability to have any ribbon hook ups, so enjoy what you have now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Per the [dialog API docs](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins), the *first* page you open in the dialog must be in the same domain. The same paragraph of docs also explicitly mentions calling from a function file.

> - The URL uses the HTTPS protocol. This is mandatory for all pages loaded in a dialog box, not just the first page loaded.
> - The domain is the same as the domain of the host page, which can be the page in a task pane or the function file of an add-in command. This is required: the page, controller method, or other resource that is passed to the displayDialogAsync method must be in the same domain as the host page.
>
> After the first page (or other resource) is loaded, a user can go to any website (or other resource) that uses HTTPS. You can also design the first page to immediately redirect to another site.

I had really wonky results trying to load a dialog from a function until I loaded Office.js and called Initialize in the dialog page (this is documented as giving you the ability to send messages back to the parent, but is not mentioned as required).